# sitemap.xml in simple-react-full-stack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, sitemap

How to use sitemap.xml or robots.txt in [simple-react-full-stack](https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack)?
I've already created sitemap using another library, but am not sure how to access such files under public folder.